# How to send data to Third party graphql endpoint in magento2

Tags: magento2, orders, api, graphql

I need to send some order information to [monday.com](http://monday.com/) using graphql

when order place I want to pass the data to monday.com graphql API

how can i send API request using graphql to monday.com

UPDATE

**Endpoint** :- https://api.monday.com/v2

**Headers** :

Authorization - AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

Content-Type - application/json

```
mutation 
{
    create_item 
    (
        board_id: 0000000001,
        item_name: "NEW",
        column_values:
        "{
            \"text9\":\"Hello world\",
            \"email\" :{\"email\":\"test@test.com\",\"text\":\"test@test.com\"},
            \"dropdown\" :{\"ids\":[6,7,8,9]},
            \"numbers\":\"3\",
            \"sales_associate\" :{\"ids\":[5]},
            \"status\" :{\"label\":\"TEST\"}
        }"
    ) 
    {
        id
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have your call working on postman? if you do, you may post it here.. then, we can post a translated version on how it should look in Magento, would that help?

Comment: hello @HerveTribouilloy, i have updated the question plz check

Comment: Has the asnwer below made your issue any better?

Answer (score 1):

the class below should help, I have simplified token, end point and not attempted to create real data provider; you may add your parser and config reader but structurally, i hope you will see what you need to execute your call now:

```
<?php

namespace Mbs\GraphQL;

class SendToMonday
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data
     */
    private $jsonHelper;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl
     */
    private $curl;

    private static $endPoint = 'https://api.monday.com/v2'; // can be stored in config later

    private static $token = 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'; // can be stored in config later

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data $jsonHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl $curl
    ) {
        $this->jsonHelper = $jsonHelper;
        $this->curl = $curl;
    }

    public function sendCallData()
    {
        $query = <<<MUTATION
            create_item 
            (
                board_id: "{$this->getBoardId()()}",
                item_name: "{$this->getNewStatus()()}",,
                column_values:
                "{
                    \"text9\":\"Hello world\",
                    \"email\" :{\"email\":\"test@test.com\",\"text\":\"test@test.com\"},
                    \"dropdown\" :{\"ids\":[6,7,8,9]},
                    \"numbers\":\"3\",
                    \"sales_associate\" :{\"ids\":[5]},
                    \"status\" :{\"label\":\"TEST\"}
                }"
            ) 
            {
                id
            }
MUTATION;

        $this->postQuery($query);
    }

    private function postQuery(string $query)
    {
        $data = $this->jsonHelper->jsonEncode(['query' => $query, 'variables' => []]);
        $this->curl->addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        $this->curl->addHeader("Content-Length", strlen($data));
        $this->curl->addHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' . self::$token);
        $this->curl->post(self::$endPoint, $data);

        $result = $this->curl->getBody();

        if (!empty($result)) {
            $result = $this->jsonHelper->jsonDecode($result);
            if (isset($result['errors'])) {
                // error wrapping
            }
        }
    }
}
```